# Generate dictionary from list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here's the original list:

```
['name', 'value', 'name', 'value', 'name', 'value']
```

And so on. I need to extract the name/value pairs into a dictionary:

```
{'name': 'value', 'name': 'value', 'name': 'value'}
```

Can someone elaborate on the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

If `L` is your original list, You can use [`zip(*[iter(L)]*2)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to group the items into pairs. The [dict constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) can take an iterable of such pairs directly

```
>>> L = ['name1', 'value1', 'name2', 'value2', 'name3', 'value3']
>>> dict(zip(*[iter(L)]*2))
{'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2', 'name3': 'value3'}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by simpler (simpler to understand?). It's hard to guess you think is simpler as I don't know what level you're at. Here's a way without using `iter` or `zip`. If you don't know what [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) does yet, you should look it up.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i, item in enumerate(L):
...     if i % 2 == 0:
...         key = item
...     else:
...         d[key] = item
... 
>>> d
{'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2', 'name3': 'value3'}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it be a bit simpler if it was known how many key/value pairs there were?

Comment: @JoshuaGilman, Knowing the length doesn't really help. I added another (longwinded) way to my answer. Is that they type of thing you mean?

Comment: Isn't this dependant on the internal implementation of zip? i.e that it tries to read one item at a time from each iterator instead of getting the first and second list eagerly?

Comment: @Maxaon3000, yes of course. It's [documented behaviour](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip)

Comment: You're right this specific pattern is right there in the docs. You should probably add the link to your answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Not to take away from anyone. I think this might be a little simpler to understand:

```
dict (zip (L[::2] , L[1::2] ))
```

Though this is less efficient for large list than gnibbler's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a function to group a sequence into fixed-length chunks. Unfortunately, this is lacking from the Python core. You could use `partition` from the [funcy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcy) library. (Side note: In other languages this is called [chunksOf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) or [grouped](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator)).

The [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) documentation suggests this function:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

And the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) documentation suggests a different way to accomplish the same thing (given in [gnibbler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26600442/402884)):

```
def grouper(iterable, n):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)
```

Once that's available, the rest of the job is trivial.

```
>>> dict(grouper(range(8), 2))
{0: 1, 2: 3, 4: 5, 6: 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> dict(zip([x for x in a[::2]], [x for x in a[1::2]]))
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}
```

`a[::2]` will get all second element from list start from `0th` element.

`a[1::2]` will get all second element from list start from `1st` element.